# How to dynamically define the path of chrome browser on windows and mac

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a function to get Chrome browser path for both windows and OS.

```
private static String getChromeBinaryPath() {
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    if (os.contains("win")) {
        return "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";
    } else if (os.contains("mac")) {
        return "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome";
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported operating system: " + os);
}
```

Is there a way, that instead of defining a statically, it will be more dynamic

Comment: You can try to use https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/  instead of local webdrivers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make your function more dynamic by allowing it to search for the Chrome browser executable in different locations based on the operating system like below.

```
private static String getChromeBinaryPath() {
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    String chromeBinaryPath = null;
    
    if (os.contains("win")) {
        chromeBinaryPath = searchChromeBinaryInWindows();
    } else if (os.contains("mac")) {
        chromeBinaryPath = searchChromeBinaryInMac();
    }
    
    if (chromeBinaryPath == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Chrome browser path not found for the current operating system: " + os);
    }
    
    return chromeBinaryPath;
}

private static String searchChromeBinaryInWindows() {
    // Possible locations to search for Chrome on Windows
    String[] possiblePaths = {
        "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
    };

    for (String path : possiblePaths) {
        File file = new File(path);
        if (file.exists()) {
            return path;
        }
    }

    return null; // Chrome not found
}

private static String searchChromeBinaryInMac() {
    // Possible locations to search for Chrome on macOS
    String[] possiblePaths = {
        "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome",
        "/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary"
    };

    for (String path : possiblePaths) {
        File file = new File(path);
        if (file.exists()) {
            return path;
        }
    }

    return null; // Chrome not found
}
```

Hope this helps!!